# Calculating PRESS Statistic/Predicted Rsquared C#

Tags: c#, statistics

I'm trying to create a method that will calculate the PRESS statistic using C# but I'm obviously not doing something right because even though I use junk data (that has a rsquared value of 0.2) I'm still getting negative totals for the press statistic. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Reference for how to calculate press statistic can be seen at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRESS_statistic

```
public double CalculatePredictedRSquared(List<MultipleRegressionInfo> listMRInfo, Vector<double> vectorArray)
    {
        double predictedRSquared = 0, press = 0, tss = 0;

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < vectorArray.Count; i++)
            {
                var matrixArray = CreateMatrix.DenseOfColumnArrays(listMRInfo.ElementAt(0).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray(), listMRInfo.ElementAt(1).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray(), 
                    listMRInfo.ElementAt(2).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray(), listMRInfo.ElementAt(3).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray(), listMRInfo.ElementAt(4).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray(), 
                    listMRInfo.ElementAt(5).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray(), listMRInfo.ElementAt(6).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray(), listMRInfo.ElementAt(7).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray(), 
                    listMRInfo.ElementAt(8).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray(), listMRInfo.ElementAt(9).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray(), listMRInfo.ElementAt(10).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray(),
                    listMRInfo.ElementAt(11).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray());
                var actualResult = vectorArray.ElementAt(i);
                var newVectorArray = CreateVector.Dense(vectorArray.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray());
                var items = MultipleRegression.NormalEquations(matrixArray, newVectorArray);

                var estimate = (items.ElementAt(0) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(0).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) + (items.ElementAt(1) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(1).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) +
                        (items.ElementAt(2) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(2).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) + (items.ElementAt(3) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(3).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) +
                        (items.ElementAt(4) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(4).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) + (items.ElementAt(5) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(5).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) +
                        (items.ElementAt(6) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(6).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) + (items.ElementAt(7) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(7).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) +
                        (items.ElementAt(8) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(8).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) + (items.ElementAt(9) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(9).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) +
                        (items.ElementAt(10) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(10).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) + (items.ElementAt(11) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(11).ListValues.ElementAt(i));

                press += actualResult - estimate;
            }

            tss += CalculateTotalSumOfSquares(vectorArray.ToList());
            predictedRSquared = 1 - (press / tss);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            predictedRSquared = 0;
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }

        return predictedRSquared;
    }
```

The Press variable returns as a negative number using real data or junk data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was painfully simple and I can't believe I didn't notice it but I wasn't squaring the actualResult - Estimate and so here is the correct code for anyone who is interested

```
public double CalculatePredictedRSquared(List<MultipleRegressionInfo> listMRInfo, Vector<double> vectorArray)
    {
        double predictedRSquared = 0, press = 0, tss = 0;

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < vectorArray.Count; i++)
            {
                var matrixArray = CreateMatrix.DenseOfColumnArrays(listMRInfo.ElementAt(0).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray(), listMRInfo.ElementAt(1).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray(), 
                    listMRInfo.ElementAt(2).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray(), listMRInfo.ElementAt(3).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray(), listMRInfo.ElementAt(4).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray(), 
                    listMRInfo.ElementAt(5).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray(), listMRInfo.ElementAt(6).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray(), listMRInfo.ElementAt(7).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray(), 
                    listMRInfo.ElementAt(8).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray(), listMRInfo.ElementAt(9).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray(), listMRInfo.ElementAt(10).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray(),
                    listMRInfo.ElementAt(11).ListValues.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray());
                var actualResult = vectorArray.ElementAt(i);
                var newVectorArray = CreateVector.Dense(vectorArray.Where((v, j) => j != i).ToArray());
                var items = MultipleRegression.NormalEquations(matrixArray, newVectorArray);
                var actualList = newVectorArray.ToList();
                var y = CalculateYIntercept(matrixArray, actualList, items);

                var estimate = (items.ElementAt(0) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(0).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) + (items.ElementAt(1) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(1).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) +
                        (items.ElementAt(2) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(2).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) + (items.ElementAt(3) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(3).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) +
                        (items.ElementAt(4) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(4).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) + (items.ElementAt(5) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(5).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) +
                        (items.ElementAt(6) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(6).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) + (items.ElementAt(7) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(7).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) +
                        (items.ElementAt(8) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(8).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) + (items.ElementAt(9) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(9).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) +
                        (items.ElementAt(10) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(10).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) + (items.ElementAt(11) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(11).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) + y;

                press += Math.Pow(actualResult - estimate, 2);
            }

            tss += CalculateTotalSumOfSquares(vectorArray.ToList());
            predictedRSquared = 1 - (press / tss);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            predictedRSquared = 0;
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }

        return predictedRSquared;
    }
```